# Make progressbar run for a period of time I determine in Android Studio

Tags: android-progressbar, countdowntimer

How do I make a progress bar run for a period of time I specify? If I want to make it run for 2 minutes for example how do I do that? Is it using "countdowntimer"? If so how do I achieve that.